# How to properly handle the timezone and daylight saving time in Java 1.6

Tags: java, timezone, save, dst

We have a legacy system, which Java 1.6 was still not upgraded, but the daylight saving time was not correctly implemented. Here is my question, in Java 1.6 how can we properly handle the timezone and daylight saving time?

Anyone can share the experience here.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a special utility to update an older version of JDK and JRE with actual timezone information. It's called [TZUpdater](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) and it's totally compatible with java 1.6. You can update your DST and timezone information running

```
java -jar tzupdater.jar
```

Keep in mind that if your application is distributable it will get Timezone information from user JDK/JRE. Otherwise it should help.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java have proven to be poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them. They are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8.

## ThreeTen-Backport

Much of the java.time functionality was back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Add that library to your Java 6 apps.

Think of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) as the *One True Time*. Forget about your own time zone. Use UTC for much of your business logic, logging, data storage, and data exchange. Generally only apply a time zone for presentation to the user.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). The `Instant` is the basic building-block of java.time.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // UTC
```

Apply a time zone. [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is automatically handled for you. Be sure to read the doc to understand the behavior.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

To learn much more, search Stack Overflow for these class names as well as `ZoneOffset`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `DateTimeFormatter`.

## Updating `tzdata`

The definitions of time zones around the world change frequently, surprisingly often. And often happen with little forewarning. (Thank you, dear politicians.)

### `tzdata` in ThreeTen-Backport

The ThreeTen-Backport library contains its own copy of the [`tzdata` time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). The ThreeTen-Backport library is occasionally updated with a fresh copy of the `tzdata`. But on occasion a time zone you may care about may be updated at the last minute. In such a situation, you need to update the data yourself inside ThreeTen-Backport. See this page: [*Update tzdb*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/update-tzdb.html).

### `tzdata` in JVM

By the way, your JVM also has a copy of the tzdata. You may want to keep that up-to-date for old code not yet updated to ThreeTen-Backport. See the Oracle [*Timezone Updater Tool*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html).

### `tzdata` in the OS

Your operating system also likely has its own copy of the tzdata. You may need to update that as well for all your other non-Java software.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).